# How to pass 3 values in lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

**Lambda functions are working perfectly:**

```
funct = (lambda a,aa,aaa: (a-aa)/aaa if aa>0 else a/aaa)
print(funct(200,100,2))
```

what I want to do is to apply this in dataframe: `df[['a','aa','aaa']]` using `.apply()`

---

```
Error: <lambda> missing 2 required positional arguments: aa and aaa
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
df['result'] = [funct(*x) for x in zip(df['a'], df['aa'], df['aaa'])]
```

But given your function, you should use vectorial code:

```
df['result'] = np.where(df['aa']>0, (df['a']-df['aa'])/df['aaa'],
                        df['a']/df['aaa'])
```

Example:

```
   a  aa  aaa    result
0  2  -1    3  0.666667
1  2   1    3  0.333333
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
funct = lambda a, aa, aaa: (a - aa) / aaa if aa > 0 else a / aaa


df["result"] = df[["a", "aa", "aaa"]].apply(lambda row: funct(*row), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   a  aa  aaa    result
0  1   2    3 -0.333333
1  4   5    6 -0.166667
```